# How to do Looping to Check Duplicate in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I want to make for each data exist on databases then do loop up to get unique data.

Here my code:

```
$id = rand(10000000,99999999);
$check_id = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sh_url WHERE sh_id='$id'");
$check_id->execute();
$count_id = $check_id->rowCount();

for ($count_id != 0) {
    $lid = $id+1;
}

$shorturl = htmlentities(base_convert($lid,20,36));

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `sh_url`(`sh_id`) VALUES (:id)");
$query->bindParam(":id", $lid);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: This code does not make any sense to me and it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use distinct keyword to do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: that not what i want, i want data insert to database when the data is unique/never exist before.

Comment: then make it unique constraint. So it will be handled automatically